MYSQL - err_lockwait try restarting transaction
I am facing err_lockwait start retrying transaction while querying in MySQL frequently. Can somebody help to resolve this issue?
I always restarted the server at that time. But I have to get rid of completely and handle the transactions properly without failing the query. So, kindly suggest an optimal solution for this to solve. Also, kindly put down the reasons why this is happening frequently. Give some points to optimise mysql database.

The occurrence of the ERR_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT error in MySQL is normal behavior when a transaction has to wait too long for a lock. This issue can be caused by other queries that are locking resources and causing delays.
To resolve this issue and properly handle transactions without failing the query, consider the following steps:
1. Use InnoDB Transactions:
Ensure you are using InnoDB as it supports transactions and row-level locking, which can help reduce locking issues.
2. Optimize Queries:
Review your queries for inefficiencies or long-running operations that could be causing locks. Use the EXPLAIN command to analyze execution plans and ensure indexes are being used effectively.
3. Set Lock Timeouts:
Configure the innodb_lock_wait_timeout setting to an appropriate value to ensure transactions do not wait too long for a lock.
4. Avoid Deadlocks:
Design your application to minimize deadlocks. One way to achieve this is by ensuring that all transactions access resources in the same order.
5. Check Isolation Levels:
Review the isolation levels of your transactions. Higher isolation levels like SERIALIZABLE can cause more locks and lock-wait issues. Consider lowering the isolation level if it is acceptable for your application.
4.Batching and Chunking:
Process large data sets in smaller batches to minimize lock duration and reduce the likelihood of lock-waits.
4. Monitoring and Analysis:
Regularly monitor database activities and analyze locking issues using tools like MySQL Enterprise Monitor or other database monitoring tools.
These steps should help you diagnose the issue and optimize your MySQL database to minimize lock-wait problems.
another tip:
If this problem occurs again, you can type: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;. This gives you information about which queries generate this LOCK.
You can also post the result to us

Thank you so much for the detailed explaination Bernd Buffen
